# How to set allowance correctly

Tags: erc-20

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Orders is  Ownable {
    function allowance(address _token) public view {
        IERC20(_token).allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    }

    function approve(address _token) public {
        uint256 MAX_INT = type(uint256).max;
        IERC20(_token).approve(address(this), MAX_INT);
    }
    
    
    function deposit(address _token, uint256 _amount) public payable {
        // uint _minAmount = 1*(10**18);
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function getContractBalance(address _token) public onlyOwner view returns(uint) {
        return IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }


}
```

And I'm trying to deposit some amount of DAI on Rinkeby Testnet. After successful deploy I'm executing `approve` function. After that I'm trying to call `deposit` but then execution have been reverted and i receive this error: `"message": "execution reverted: Dai/insufficient-allowance"` and when i check `allowance` returns `0` any idea how to solve it?

Using remix

Answer (score 2):

The ERC20 `approve` function approves that the given address may transfer tokens from `msg.sender`. In your code the smart contract is calling the `approve` function of the token, this means that the contract is `msg.sender`.

The ERC20 `approve` function:

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    address owner = _msgSender();
    _approve(owner, spender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

What you are trying to achieve is setting the `owner` of the `approve` function to `tx.origin`. Unfortunately this is not possible. The user should call the token `approve` function directly, not through your smart contract.